# "IndexError: list index out of range" While using recursion on lists

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, indexing, range

I'm a programming student and I have just recently started working in Python. I started with learning Rackett which has a very different approach. While trying to use recursion in combination with a for statement I ran into "IndexError: list index out of range". This is my code:

```
def search_matching_pokemon(p, l):
    lp = []
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        if p[-1] == l[i][0]:
            print ('Found one')
            poke = l.pop(i)
            lp = lp + [poke]
            print (f'List is now {lp}')
            search_matching_pokemon(poke, l)    #problem with the range
        else:
            print ('Trying a different pokémon')
    return lp
```

I think my function doesn't take the reduced list when recursing, at least not during the
`range(len(l) - 1)`
Help would be very much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I really see no reason to use recursion here. What is an example input?

Comment: You are removing items from the list you are iterating over. That results in the observed IndexError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List "l" becomes empty and you are still trying to run for loop.Don't run this loop when list is empty.
Also the loop should be for i in range(len(l)).

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without more information, but it looks like the problem is that you are popping from the list while iterating over it. Again, without more information (like what you are trying to do), I can't be sure how to fix this.

Comment: I was trying to solve a path problem through a list. Rakshith was right, but thanks a lot for helping!